# Ruby on Rails: Validate a user has selected a checkbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

In my RoR application, I have a table of records with a checkbox against each record so that the user can select and delete multiple records.

This works through the following code.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Subscription</th>
            <th>Emails Received</th>
            <th colspan=3>Available Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <%= form_tag destroy_multiple_contacts_path, method: :delete do %>
    <tbody>
        <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td><%= check_box_tag "contact_ids[]", contact.id %></td>
                <td><%= contact.firstname %></td>
                <td><%= contact.surname %></td>
                <td><%= contact.email %></td>
                <td><%= human_boolean(contact.subscription) %></td>
                <td><%= contact.recipients.count %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Show', contact_path(contact) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(contact) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', contact_path(contact), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>

    <%= submit_tag "Delete Selected", {:class => "btn btn-danger btn-sm" } %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def destroy_multiple
    Contact.destroy(params[:contact_ids])
    redirect_to contacts_path
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :contacts do
  collection do
     delete 'destroy_multiple'
  end
end
```

However this is lacking validation and users are currently able to click the delete button without any checkbox being selected - this causes the system to error.

Is it possible to display an error message if the user clicks delete without selecting a checkbox or to only allow a user to click delete if they have selected a checkbox?

Comment: @KevalGohil and presented probably the easiest and fastest solution. you can probably get fancier with java script, but i'd suggest  putting things in the controller is probably far easier and significantly faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flash message

in controller do

```
def destroy_multiple
   if params[:contact_ids].blank?
       flash[:notice] = "No contacts selected"
       redirect_to :back
   else 
      Contact.destroy(params[:contact_ids])
      redirect_to contacts_path
   end
end
```

in view add above table

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting a few javascript approaches that spring to mind as you've tagged this post with javascript

1. Disable the delete button and only enable it once a checkbox has been ticked. This will requiring adding an eventListener to each checkbox that checks if any checkboxes are ticked every time the user interacts with a checkbox and then enables/disables the button appropriately.
2. Add an event listener to the enable button. On submission, ensure at least one checkbox is checked or don't submit the form and show an appropriate message.

Here's a basic implementation of the second approach

```
$(function() {

  function noContactSelected(){
    var checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'));
    var checked = checkboxes.filter(function(checkbox) { return checkbox.checked})
    return checked.length == 0;
  }

  function showNoneCheckedMsg(){
    var message = document.createTextNode('Please check at least one contact');
    document.querySelector('.error').appendChild(message);
  }

  $(".btn").click(function(event){
    if (noContactSelected()){
      event.preventDefault();
      showNoneCheckedMsg();
    }
  });

});
```

In the view, you would need to include a p or div element with `class="error"`

It is always recommended that you implement server side validation, which Keval Gohil's answer addresses, in the event that the user does not have javascript enabled.